# T-SQL regarding current sales and previous sales

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales](
[SaleDate] [datetime] NULL,
[SaleAmt] [money] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How would I retrieve the sum of sales by month, but also show the previous month figures.

I thought the following would work but it does not

```
select 
    DATEPART(m,s1.saledate), SUM(s1.SaleAmt), SUM(s2.SaleAmt) 
from 
    sales s1 
inner join 
    Sales s2 on DATEPART(m, DateAdd(m, -1, s2.saledate)) = DATEPART(m, s1.saledate)
group by 
    DATEPART(m, s1.saledate)
```

Comment: what do you mean by  'show the previous month figures.' could you provide a sample of the outpout that you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have come up with quite a simple solution, although I dont think its quite as good as using a self-join approach

```
select DATEPART(m,s1.saledate) as Month,
SUM(s1.SaleAmt) as CurrentSales,
(select SUM(SaleAmt) 
from Sales where DATEPART(m,saledate)=DATEPART(m,s1.saledate)-1) as PreviousSales from             
sales s1
group by DATEPART(m,s1.saledate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your desired output, one of the following solutions should work for you.  i would likely lean more towards the second solution but it all depends on what you want to see:

```
select
  s2.month as 'C-MONTH',
  s1.month as 'P-MONTH',
  s2.amt as 'C-AMT',
  s1.amt as 'P-AMT'
from
(
  select 
    datepart(m, saledate) as month,
    sum(SaleAmt) as amt
  from 
    Sales
  group by
    datepart(m, saledate)
) s1,
(
  select 
    datepart(m, saledate) as month,
    sum(SaleAmt) as amt
  from 
    Sales
  group by
    datepart(m, saledate)
) s2
where
  s2.month = s1.month + 1
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66ad9/1

```
select
  s2.month as 'C-MONTH',
  s1.month as 'P-MONTH',
  s2.amt as 'C-AMT',
  s1.amt as 'P-AMT'
from
(
  select 
    datepart(m, saledate) as month,
    sum(SaleAmt) as amt
  from 
    Sales
  group by
    datepart(m, saledate)
) s1
right outer join
(
  select 
    datepart(m, saledate) as month,
    sum(SaleAmt) as amt
  from 
    Sales
  group by
    datepart(m, saledate)
) s2
on
  s2.month = s1.month + 1
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a670/1